# Gradle build task for Scala Library does not include library code in jar

Tags: scala, gradle, gradle-scala

Result of `gradle build`

[image: Result]

Project Structure

[image: Structure]

Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'scala'
    id 'org.gradle.playframework' version '0.9'
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "5.0.0-beta"
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java-base'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.0.0"
}


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
    maven {
        name "lightbend-maven-release"
        url "https://repo.lightbend.com/lightbend/maven-releases"
    }
    ivy {
        name "lightbend-ivy-release"
        url "https://repo.lightbend.com/lightbend/ivy-releases"
        layout "ivy"
    }
}


dependencies {
    // Use Scala 2.12 in our library project
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.8'

    // Use Scalatest for testing our library
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.0.8'

    // Need scala-xml at test runtime
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.2.0'
}

group 'com.project.integration-service.lib'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

What am I missing? I have inspected the generated JAR file manually and my library is not there.

I need to use the JAR in a different project and I can't do so since I can't get the plugin to work.

I think 'NO-SOURCE' means that it can't find my root directory.

Here is my project structure: